# Out-Standing Behavior in AXI Protocol

Tags: c++, hardware

I am trying to implement the axi outstanding feature in CPP, i tried to search if there is 
already a model in CPP, did not find alot.
Is there such model ? If not, Is there any diff in terms of READ and WRITE when it comes to outstanding ?

Comment: Are you trying to simulate an AXI bus in software?

Comment: Somehow yes, I am trying to simulate the outstanding behaviour of the AXI.
So when there is outstanding of 16 and a high latency from teh memory it will not affect the ovelall performance.

Comment: One more clarification, are you writing an actual bus simulation where you implement the bus logic in software, or are you just providing some sort of logical simulation? Better yet, can you describe the use case in more detail?

Comment: I am providing some sort of logic, the use case is to examine the memory latency with AXI outstanding which shoud compensate on the latency.

Comment: Then as I understand it, this is not a C++ question, what you actually want is to understand the behavior of AXI, and you should come back with a more specific question that is directly C++ related. I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with ARM's published AXI specifications also if you're abrigador stimulating AXI behavior.

Comment: it is not exactly the case, thanks for your reply